# Default arguments syntax and general syntax in c++

Tags: c++

What is the difference between below function prototype declarations?

```
int a(double = 0, double = 10);
int a(double j = 0, double a = 10);
```

Comment: There's technically no difference.

Comment: @AlexStacy That's all, no details required.

Comment: Actually, argument names are not needed in declarations. They might be there for convenience (copy/pasted from implementation). They might be used in documentation (e.g. Doxygen can use them).

Comment: @AlexStacy "There's no difference" is the explanation.

Comment: In your last edit, you introduced a syntax error: I doubt that `void f(double = 0, double = 5, int )` will compile without complaints. (Last parameter without default!)

Comment: @Alex Stacy This declaration void f(double = 0, double = 5, int) is invalid.

Comment: **Don't change the original question into another one completely different.** It makes the already given answers obsolete. Writing _"read the question again"_ is not sufficient.

Comment: For the records: `void f(int x, int y);` and `void f(double, double, int)`... are unrelated. Read about [polymorphism -> Overloading](https://catonmat.net/cpp-polymorphism) concerning this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are both function declarations. Parameter names in function declarations are purely for documentation. So there is no technical difference.